# cmake force parallel .C.o compilation before linking

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I have a project with 5 libraries that each comes from 10 C++ source files, then 10 executables that depend on the libraries. Each library also depends on the previous one. Using CMake and then 'make -j 50' on a 48-core Ubuntu machine, I first have to wait for each library to build on 10 cores or fewer (mostly fewer, as one .C file takes several minutes to compile), then my executables build in parallel.

I would like to first run all the .C.o compilations in parallel on all .C source files (I know how to get that list into a CMake variable), then running only the linker in the order specified by the dependencies.

Is there a way to do that with CMake, for example by setting a phony target or something similar? (I only want to recompile the .C files that have been modified).

Comment: If you are using GCC, I would recommend to give clang a try because it tends to have faster compile times. Also, if CMake is generating Makefiles, then I would recommend trying the [Ninja generator/build system](https://martine.github.io/ninja/) instead. CMake starting with version 2.8.9 has Ninja generator built-in. See [this](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/434) for some more info.

Comment: Have you tried running each of the library targets separately?  Something like `for lib in lib1 lib2...; do make -j10 $lib & done; wait`.  Also, why are your .C files taking so long to compile?

Comment: @SchighSchagh yes I have heard of Ninja and may try it but I don't think it will solve my problem (there are dependencies between the libs and executables, etc).

Comment: @Jason does not work (I guess since second lib depends on first, etc). Long compile time is for lots of template code (in this case, operators between generic images that can have 15 or so different pixel types (using boost::variant), so the 15^2 instantiations of operator+, operator+=, etc have to be compiled)

Comment: It may be better to roll the separate libraries into a single library, since they all depend on eachother successively.  Or possibly write a custom Makefile with a generic rule for the object files.  I hope someone corrects me if I'm wrong, but I'm not sure CMake will track cross-target source dependencies.  On a slightly unrelated note, `extern` templates might help with the compile times.

Comment: @Jason well, one lib is Core, then ImageProc, PointCloud, Graphics, Robotics. I don't want people who only need Core to have to link against a giant library full of openGL code and such. Yes, the templates are all extern (you still have to compile those 15^2 instantiations of each image operator at some point, no way around it; clang is just as slow on it as g++). In an older system where we had a custom dependencies calculator we could do massively parallel .C.o but for this project we want to use CMake.

Comment: @LaurentItti One solution may be to create a fake single target including all the source files for each of the libs (`${LIB1_SRC} ${LIB2_SRC} ...`), and have each of the actual libs depend on it.  CMake may try to recompile the files, but if you use [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org), the duplicate compiles should be fast.

Comment: hehe, yes, but that's the part I have no idea how to do in CMake.

Comment: @LaurentItti See below :).

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to add a false target consisting of all the sources for each of the library targets in CMake.  An example CMakeLists.txt might be...

```
set(ONE_SRC one/a.c one/b.c)
set(TWO_SRC two/a.c two/b.c)

# pre-compile
add_library(all ${ONE_SRC} ${TWO_SRC})

add_library(one ${ONE_SRC})
add_library(two ${TWO_SRC})

add_dependencies(one all)
add_dependencies(two one)
```

The *liball.so* target will compile all the sources necessary for all the other libs, and it should break the false dependency between the source files of *libone.so* and *libtwo.so* when you run `make`, `ninja`, whatever... it will maximize compile parallelism across targets.

CMake *may* not be smart enough to compile `${ONE_SRC} ${TWO_SRC}` files only once.  However, this can be fixed using [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org), which will cache pre-processed files.  It has the added benefit of reducing any identical re-compile times.

A simple config for ccache is to add symlinks to the ccache binaries in a local `$PATH`.

```
jason@io ~ $ ll ~/bin/ccache
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 c++ -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 cc -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 Apr 27 21:38 clang -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 Apr 27 21:38 clang++ -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 g++ -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 Oct  6  2013 gcc -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-c++ -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -> /usr/bin/ccache*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 15 May 12  2013 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -> /usr/bin/ccache*
```

The ccache environment variables are relatively straightforward.

```
# ccache

export CCACHE_DIR="/var/ccache/${USER}"
export CCACHE_SIZE="4G"
export CCACHE_COMPRESS="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ninja build generator on linux solved this problem for me (in the year 2021):

```
> cmake -G Ninja <path-to-source>
> ninja
```

It seems that the makefile generator adds too many dependencies...